# How to evaluate variables within LaTeX within Rmd or qmd docs

Tags: latex, r-markdown, quarto

I want to evaluate these variables within LaTeX, but the inline code convention `r ` will not evaluate within $$ $$.

```
K <- 1e3
P <- 0.6
```

$$Binomial(k= `r K`, p = `r P`)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can execute inline code within LaTeX environment in quarto or RMarkdown.

Here's a workaround which displays the intended output.

Chunk options: `{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}`

Chunk contents:

```
K <- 1e3
P <- 0.6

cat("$$Binomial(k = ", K, ", p= ", P, ")$$")
```

Result:

[image]